# CoffeeScript getting the function code

Tags: coffeescript

Is there a way to get the CoffeeScript code of a function, similar to the javascript function toString() method? It will be useful for documentation generation.

Comment: You can still use `Function.prototype.toString`, but it will return the code compiled into Javascript.

Comment: All functions that present in JavaScript presents in CoffeeScript. What is this question about?

Comment: The question is about getting the actual CoffeeScript code, not the generated javascript.

Comment: The best solution I can think of would be to `toString()` the function and then pass it through `js2coffee`.  It won't be the same code, but it ought to be fairly close.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but the code is not that good, I guess I'll have to write a script that extracts the coffeescript code and generate javascript to show it.

Comment: @user2032804 I've used http://js2coffee.org/ many times and found that it works well. I assume this is a one-off thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Coffeescript Redux](https://github.com/michaelficarra/CoffeeScriptRedux) - the next generation Coffee Script compiler should be able to produce [source maps](http://edanhewitt.com/slurp/introduction-to-javascript-source-maps/).